# Entity framework Core. Sort child entity and then internally sort childs children?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to sort a tables child table and then sort the children of the child table.

Is there anyway to do this in a nice way with eager loading?

This does not work and sorts actually nothing.

```
await _dbContext.MainTable
            .Include(m => m.Chapter.OrderBy(c => c.SortingOrder))
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Paragraph.OrderBy(p => p.SortingOrder))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select and then perform the shorting. Shorting will not be done at the time of include.

Comment: i see a lot of github issues that have been open for 3-5 years on a need for ordered collections.

This is a "solution" but shows a clear lack of maturity in the toolset which makes me a little disappointed in it